# sed - inserting a comma after every 4th line in plain text file

Tags: sed, awk

I am trying to insert a comma after the values on line 1, 4, 8, etc using sed,

```
sed '0-4 s/$/,/' in.txt > in2.txt
```

For some reason this isn't working so I was wondering if anyone has any solutions doing this using awk, sed, or any other methods.

The error I am getting is

```
sed: 1: "0-4 s/$/,/": invalid command code -
```

Currently my data looks like this:

```
        City
        Address
        Zip Code
        County
```

and I was trying to format it like this

```
        City,
        Address
        Zip Code
        County
```

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0-4` indeed is not well-formed `sed` syntax.  I would use `awk` for this, but it is easy to do it with either.

```
sed 's/$/,/;n;n;n' file
```

which substitutes one line and prints it, then prints the next three lines without substitution, then starts over from the beginning of the script; or

```
awk 'NR % 4 == 1 {sub(/$/,",")} {print}'
```

which does the substitution if the line number modulo 4 is 1, then prints unconditionally.

Sed's addressing modes are sometimes a tad disappointing; there is no standard way to calculate line offsets, relative or in reference to e.g. the end of the file.  Of course, `awk` is more complex, but if you can only learn one or the other, definitely go for `awk`.  (Or in this day and age, Python or Perl -- a much better investment.)

Comment: thank you very much, that worked! will definitely give awk some more attention.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1~4s/$/,/' file
```